# Можно ли программно получать события об popup уведомлениях в linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome

В gnome (gdm3) программы могут генерировать уведомления, показывающиеся в верхней части экрана, например, мессенджеры могут уведомлять о входящем сообщении. notify-send позволяет генерировать такие уведомления. Можно ли повесить событие на создание каждого такого уведомления через bash/c++/python?

Comment: Если кратко, то `dbus-monitor --session interface='org.freedesktop.Notifications'` (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/268702)